# Accessing Static Files In Go Project

Tags: go, environment-variables, environment

I have a go project in  `~/go/src/project-folder` with the following structure

```
.
+--app
   +--main.go
   +--main (binary)
+--config
   +--config.go
+--.env
```

The config package uses the `github.com/joho/godotenv` package to load the `.env` file and is called in `main.go` to access certain data (like the PORT to run my webserver on).

If I `cd` into the `app` folder and run `./main` the project works as expected but if I am in say my home directory and run

```
~/go/src/project-folder/app/main
```

I get

```
open /.env: no such file or directoryError
```

I use the go package `path/filepath` in the `config` package to access the `.env` file.

This is the code in the config package that reads the `.env` file
**config/config.go**

```golang
package config

import (
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"
)

var env map[string]string 

func init() {
    envPath,_:= filepath.Abs("../.env");
    en, err := godotenv.Read(envPath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }

    env = en
}

func ENV() map[string]string {
    return env
}
```

**app/main.go**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "project/routes"
    "project/config"
    "project/models"
)

func main() {
    router := routes.MakeRouter()
    defer models.DB().Close()
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":" + config.ENV()["PORT"], router)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
}
```

**GOPATH**
`GOPATH="/home/fanan/go"`

It seems like the path is being referenced from where I call the binary file and not where the binary file is located.

Is there a way to ensure the path is relative to where the binary file is located and not where it is called?

Comment: Try running the code from the root folder instead of the folder containing main.go

Comment: @kofoworola still fives the `no such file` error

Comment: Can you post the code where you set the folder path?

Comment: whats your GOPATH?

Comment: @AshwinShirva my GOPATH is `GOPATH="/home/fanan/go"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems like the path is being referenced from where I call the binary file and not where the binary file is located.

Of course it is. That is how computers and file paths work.

Add a command line flag or environment variable to your program which lets you set the path to your static files. (Note that is absolutely impossible to locate the source folder in Go binaries.)

Comment: @FananDala Note that this is a 100% duplicate.

Comment: Please share the link to the original question